# Implementing Scrolling like that of Twitter profile in android app

Tags: android, animation, twitter

I am new to android. I am trying to implement Scrolling thing like that of twitter's profile activity. Tweets, Photos and Favorites are in tabs, above the tabs there is basic profile data such as name, about, location with two pictures and also a button. When it is scrolled that part gets hidden and tabs are snapped up at top now you can go through tweets and when you scroll down it comes back.

I have added tabs to my activity. Every tab is loaded via fragments. I added tabs using PagerView.

here's my activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/action_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/cover"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/image_background"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cover"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            android:background="@drawable/image_background"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cover"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">



        <com.example.vickyzia.activity.Misc.SlidingTabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabs"></com.example.vickyzia.activity.Misc.SlidingTabLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

I want to add that scrolling event to this activity. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use special [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html)

Answer (score 3):

Example of a Twitter Like Profile scroll Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<include layout="@layout/toptoolbar"/>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/prime_white_1">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/spacing_largest"
            app:contentScrim="@color/prime_white_1"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <include
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
                layout="@layout/profile_header_layout"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/profile_toolbar_collapse"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                android:background="@color/transparent">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/profile_tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/prime_grey_9"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/prime_green_1"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/spacing_small"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/profile_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```